# ISA server 2004

Tags: isa-server, windows-sbs-2003

I have a problem with setting up ISA 2004 on Windows SBS 2003. The problem is after setting up the deny and access rules: I added the group of users that I wanted to deny. It works but for everyone rather than the target user group. Hence, on checking monitoring I have found out that there is no client username: although I did tick the option of authenticate users. 
From the forums I learned that ISA client needs to be setup for the rules to work and users get properly authenticated. I finally installed ISA client and configured it, again the same thing.

What I have also figured out is that the traffic first gets sent to the DNS server and then to the desitnation ip. Is there something I am missing now, I have run out of ideas 
ps: DNS and ISA are same ip address.

Comment: So what kind of traffic are you trying to block?

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that ISA 2004 is a bit of a pain in the butt for this kind of setup - the authentication has been touchy whenever I've tried to get it working on its own.

Try taking a look at the firewall client - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10193 - it should help with most authentication issues.

Comment: Hi tim, thanks for the quick response. I have already tried with the ISA client, and it still is the same. Although it is worth mentioning that ISA and DNS are same machine (win sbs2003).